# How to use dev center dashboard failure logs

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-dev-center

Recently I released an app for Windows 10, and while it works fine on my laptop, tablet and phone, it seems that many users in the real world are experiencing it crashing after the splash screen displaying.

The failure log string name is:

> STOWED_EXCEPTION_80131537_Amiibo_Checklist.dll!Unknown

The Stack traces are

> Frame Image   Function    Offset
>
> 1 amiibo_checklist_7ff80a900000       0x451D33
>
> 2  amiibo_checklist_7ff80a900000       0x44EC33
>
> 3  amiibo_checklist_7ff80a900000       0x364C71
>
> 4  amiibo_checklist_7ff80a900000       0x37081E
>
> 5  amiibo_checklist_7ff80a900000       0x3C95F6

(screenshots at https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUbbw.jpg)

How do I utilize this information to solve my bug?